# How to change magento home page with non cms page?

Tags: magento-1.9, routing

I have one page `www.abstract.id/landingpage` and I wanna make it as my home page, and the url changed to `www.abstract.id`

I have a block, controller, etc, helper and the frontend xml & page.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you haven't create CMS page then create cms page of **landingpage**
2. Now, Go to **system > Configuration > Web > Default page** section, Select **landingpage**. Please check this http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2267375/69f8cc6e9b3d2e40c022712a5b53fbc8
3. Save it.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not my solution. I need to change my non CMS route to home page route because I've created a non CMS page

Comment: Create cms page and call your non CMS page into cms page like this `{{block type="core/template" template="templateFolder/your_template.phtml"}}` and set this page.